# MySQL: Updating a column with a concatenation of results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column with a string in it, and due to a bug some of the string values are wrong.  So I want to fix the strings by taking the original string and concatenating information from a select to it. Ideally it would be something like:

```
UPDATE table as t
SET t.string = SELECT CONCAT(t.string, 
                             (SELECT fix FROM othertable where id=t.id )
                            );
```

But of course, I can't do that using `concat`.
I have to say I've not got very far with any other method.
Anyone have an ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the subquery is guaranteed to return just one value, you could simply drop the `SELECT` keyword before `CONCAT`:

```
UPDATE table as t
SET t.string = CONCAT(t.string, 
                      (SELECT fix FROM othertable where id=t.id)
                     );
```

If the subquery may return more than one value, a quick fix could be to apply [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) like this:

```
UPDATE table as t
SET t.string = CONCAT(t.string, 
                      (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(fix) FROM othertable where id=t.id)
                     );
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below:

```
UPDATE
table as t

INNER JOIN 
othertable as o

ON
t.id = o.id

SET
t.string = CONCAT(t.string, o.fix)
```

note that in MySQL (as above) it's sort of different than MSSQL which doesn't use the keyword FROM.